# Why does Starfire have a magical girl transformation scene?

Tags: character, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-vs-teen-titans

In "***Justice League vs Teen Titans***", halfway in the film the Titans have their first fight against the Trigon demons. In this scene, Kori aka Starfire, is given a cliche anime magical girl transformation scene, where her street clothes magically get shred and her normal uniform/dress appears out of no where, with a magical glow censoring everything.

Why does she get this magical girl transformation scene? This is not typical of her powers, or of DC in general.

At least Jamie has an excuse, his battle armor has always been hidden inside the blue scarab fused with his spine.

Comment: They all get transformation scenes, not just Starfire. I suppose the animators/storyboarders are fans of that kind of thing. (Supposedly Starfire's sequence resembles that of Hibiki from the second season of the anime series Symphogear.)

Comment: So tweenage boys will watch more?

Comment: @sanpaco it wasn't in the trailer.

Answer (score 6):

She had that transformation scene as a nod to Sailor Moon as confirmed by Sam Liu and James Tucker themselves in this [corresponding tweets](https://twitter.com/_samliu_/status/814713983726821376):

[image]

And it was there to make it look cool and it did look cool to me ;)

Comment: Cool! I was about to say this probably has something to do with homage to anime. Interesting answer!